# Get epoch from string in script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, terminal, epoch

I have an openvpn status file with content:

```
OpenVPN STATISTICS
Updated,Tue Nov  5 16:45:50 2019
...
```

And I want to parse update time in my script, to get to know if vpn is on.

This is my script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logDate=$(sudo cat /home/ubuntu/vpn/openvpn-status.log | grep Update| awk -F "," '{print $2}') 

logEpoch=$(date -d $logDate +"%s")
```

When I run same commands in terminal, it works ok, but when I run script it gives me an error:

```
date: extra operand ‘5’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

Comment: There might be a better way to do this. When active, the vpn should have an entry in your routing table. Try `netstat -anr` when the vpn is up then again when it is not. I'm not running OpenVPN otherwise I would check

Comment: Quote your variables.

Comment: `grep foo | awk '{print}'` is an anti-pattern. Use `awk '/foo/{print}'` instead. Also google UUOC.

Comment: Try to change `date` on this way: `date -d "$logDate" +"%s"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add Quotes when use your variables.
The script should works with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logDate=$(sudo cat /home/ubuntu/vpn/openvpn-status.log | grep Update| awk -F "," '{print $2}') 

logEpoch=$(date -d "$logDate" +"%s")
echo "$logEpoch"
```

The explanation is here:  [mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) – @Ed Morton